# DataGridView Replacing Null Value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to replace null values in my datagridview in VB. Data is being read in from an access data base. Every time I run it I get an error relating to "System.NullReferenceException" .

```
Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
  Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If e.ColumnIndex = Me.DataGridView1.Columns(7).Index Then _
      ' AndAlso (e.Value IsNot Nothing) Then


        With Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)

            If e.Value.Equals("") Then
                e.Value = "very bad"
            End If
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated!!

Comment: "" is not the same thing as DBNull and neither an empty string nor DBNull are the same as Nothing which is the cause of a NRE

Comment: Please show your code for the `Access` call that return's your data and then is set to the `DataGridView`... This should be handled in the call and ***not in the cellformatting event***...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? `Private Sub frmViewAll_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        
       Me.TblStudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentRecords1DataSet.tblStudents) `

Comment: Check if the cells is `DBNull`, replace with some string value (like `""`)

Comment: @Donncha no, how `do you query your data`...

Comment: You dont need to replace DBNull - the DGV is adept at ignoring them as needed, and DBNull wont result in NRE.  AndAlso if e,RowIndex is the New user row, you'll get the NRE.

Comment: @Codexer  `SELECT        ID, StudentID, FirstName, Surname, [Password], MCQ, Project, Exam, TotalMarks, StudentResult
FROM            tblStudents` Is what is bringing it in in the query builder

Comment: Ok wrap them in `IsNull(yourcolumnname, '')` I see you are looking at column 7. If that is the case just wrap the column that is 7... I said to do them all as I don't know your specs you have setup.

Comment: `IsNull(StudentResult, ' ')` keeps throwing an SQL Exception Error

Comment: `IIF(ISNULL(yourcolumn),'',yourcolumn)` I forgot it's `Access`...

Comment: Ok Thats works, great!! Now I only have one issue and thats when i go into DataGridView to Bind the grid to to the data but it is not showing up the new column that  I want to add in that does not have the null value, only give me the list of columns that are originally brought in, Something to do with the table Adapter

Comment: Nevermind, It's there now. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Donncha please see answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the actual database call. You can check if any of the fields are `Null`and replace them there. Then you do not have to handle them in code...

```
 IIF(ISNULL(yourcolumn),'', yourcolumn)
```

This will check if the column is `null` and if so replace it with empty string, otherwise it will return the value...

Answer (score 0):

Try `IsDBNull`:

```
Dim abc As Integer 

abc= IIf(IsDBNull(DGVInvoice.Rows(max).Cells(3).Value) = True, 0, DGVInvoice.Rows(max).Cells(3).Value)
```

`DGVInvoice` is your DataGrid and `max` is your maximum row number.